# In Perl, how can I check for the existence of Socket options without generating warnings?

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I'm checking for the existence and default values of various socket options using Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Socket;

if (defined(SO_BROADCAST)) {
    print("SO_BROADCAST defined\n");
}

if (defined(SO_REUSEPORT)) {
    print("SO_REUSEPORT defined\n");
}
```

When I run this it outputs:

`SO_BROADCAST defined`

`Your vendor has not defined Socket macro SO_REUSEPORT, used at ./checkopts.pl line 9`

Is there a way to do this without generating warnings in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask whether the sub has been defined, not whether the expression's value is defined:

```
if (defined &SO_REUSEPORT) { ... }
```

The [documentation for `defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) explains:

> You may also use `defined(&func)` to check whether subroutine `&func` has ever been defined. The return value is unaffected by any forward declarations of `&func`. Note that a subroutine which is not defined may still be callable: its package may have an `AUTOLOAD` method that makes it spring into existence the first time that it is called—see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

If the sub is exported into your namespace, it has to be defined.

Comment: Why do you check for a subroutine define?  Are these actually defined as subroutines in Socket.pm and not as constants?

Comment: @Robert The constants *are* subs! See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions

Comment: You're answer is better than the one I originally picked.

Answer (score 9):

That message is coming from `AUTOLOAD` in Socket.pm. When it finds a constant that isn't supported, it `croak`s. You can catch that with an [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
 use Socket;

 if( defined eval { SO_REUSEPORT } ) {
      ...;
      }
```