# Perl: Checking for the Existence of socket options

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

This is a continuation of my previous question:

[In Perl, how can I check for the existence of Socket options without generating warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216636/in-perl-how-can-i-check-for-the-existence-of-socket-options-without-generating-w)

If I run the following code I get the result I expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use Socket qw(:all);

my %opts;

if ( defined( eval { SO_REUSEPORT } ) ) {
    $opts{'SO_REUSEPORT'}
        =  {opt_level =>SOL_SOCKET,opt_name=>SO_REUSEPORT,opt_print=>\&sock_str_flag};
} else {
    print "SO_REUSEPORT undefined\n";
    $opts{'SO_REUSEPORT'}
        =  {opt_level =>0,opt_name=>0,opt_print=>undef};
}
=head
# IPV6 options
if ( defined( eval { IPV6_DONTFRAG } ) ) {
    $opts{'IPV6_DONTFRAG'}
        =  {opt_level =>IPPROTO_IPV6,opt_name=>IPV6_DONTFRAG,opt_print=>\&sock_str_flag};
} else {
    print "IPV6_DONTFRAG undefined\n";
    $opts{'IPV6_DONTFRAG'}
        =  {opt_level =>0,opt_name=>0,opt_print=>undef};
}
=cut
```

It outputs:

```
anon@perl$ ./test.pl 
SO_REUSEPORT undefined
```

But if I uncomment the block for `IPV6_DONTFRAG` I get:

```
Bareword "IPV6_DONTFRAG" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 17.
Bareword "IPV6_DONTFRAG" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./test.pl line 17.
```

Why is one undefined bareword causing it to barf and the other not?  And how can the error be propagating out of the `eval { }` block?

**Edit**

Apparently, `SO_REUSEPORT` is exported by [Socket.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DAPM/perl-5.10.1/ext/Socket/Socket.pm) in some manner as it's in the @EXPORT array.  So apparently it's defined but using it throws an error which the eval catches.

That still doesn't explain what's going on with `IPV6_DONTFRAG`.  I suppose I would need to define it myself and then just call `getsockopt` to check if it's supported...

Comment: Why did someone mark this down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend writing it this way:

```
if ( defined( &IPV6_DONTFRAG ) ) {
    $opts{'IPV6_DONTFRAG'}
        =  {opt_level =>IPPROTO_IPV6,opt_name=>&IPV6_DONTFRAG,opt_print=>\&sock_str_flag};
} else {
    print "IPV6_DONTFRAG undefined\n";
    $opts{'IPV6_DONTFRAG'}
        =  {opt_level =>0,opt_name=>0,opt_print=>undef};
}
```

Note the added ampersand in the value for `opt_name`, which evades constraints due to `strict 'subs'`.

The [documentation for `defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) explains:

> You may also use `defined(&func)` to check whether subroutine `&func` has ever been defined. The return value is unaffected by any forward declarations of `&func`. Note that a subroutine which is not defined may still be callable: its package may have an `AUTOLOAD` method that makes it spring into existence the first time that it is called—see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

For example, with `SO_BROADCAST`

```
if (defined &SO_BROADCAST) {
  print "SO_BROADCAST = ", SO_BROADCAST, "\n";
}
```

the output on my machine is

```
SO_BROADCAST = 6
```

Comment: So Socket.pm defines these as subroutines which return the correct constant value to pass to functions like `socket` and `getsockopt`?

Comment: @Robert Yes, that's the general idea. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work with IPV6_DONTFRAG.  I still get the bareword / strict subs error.

Comment: @Robert Did you use &IPV6_DONTFRAG (note the leading ampersand) as I did in my example?

Comment: @gbacon: Yes I did.  With `&SO_REUSEPORT` it worked fine, but with `&IPV6_DONTFRAG` I still get the bareword / strict subs error.

Comment: @Robert In *both* defined(&IPV6...) and opt_name=>&IPV6...?

Comment: @gbacon:  Take a look at this:  http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#TECHNICAL-NOTES

Comment: @gbacon:  My bad.  Forgot to put the `&` in both places.  It works.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the IPV6_DONTFRAG bareword issue, it looks like Perl checks for barewords at compile time, not run time, as documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).  Eval is a construct to swallow runtime errors, so it won't help you here.  It's like trying to handle a syntax error in C++ by sticking the offending code in a try/catch block.